# Gamma Function Identity using Weierstrass Formulation

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I want to derive some identities for $\Gamma(z)$ given 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = ze^{\gamma z} \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{z}{k} \right) e^{-z/k}.
\end{equation*}
I have already derived
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} = -\frac{1}{z} - \gamma - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z + k} - \frac{1}{k}.
\end{equation*}
From this, I would like to derive the relationship
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)} - \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} - \frac{1}{z} = 0.
\end{equation}
I would then like to use this to show that $\Gamma(z + 1) = Cz\Gamma(z)$ for some constant $C$.

From here it is easy (meaning I have done it) to show that $\lim_{z \to 0} z \Gamma(z) = 1$, which implies that $C = \Gamma(1)$.  I would finally like to show that $\Gamma(1) = 1$.

I order to prove the first relationship, I have tried using the logarithmic derivative identity above , but to little avail.  I have even tried just working from $\Gamma(1)z\Gamma(z)$ to arrive to $\Gamma(z+1)$ and I get close, but there is an extra term in my product that should not be there.  Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is straightforward. You have
$$\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-\frac1z-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^\infty
\left(\frac1{z+k}-\frac1k\right).$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}=-\frac1{z+1}-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^\infty
\left(\frac1{z+1+k}-\frac1k\right).$$
Subtracting gives
$$\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}-
\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=\frac1z-\frac1{z+1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty
\left(\frac{1}{z+k}-\frac1{z+k+1}\right).$$
The sum telescopes to $1/(z+1)$.

The logarithmic derivative of $z\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1)^{-1}$
vanishes, so that $z\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1)^{-1}$ is constant.

Finally
$$\frac1{\Gamma(1)}=e^\gamma\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k+1}{k}e^{-1/k}
=\exp\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\gamma+\log(N+1)-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1k\right)\right)$$
etc.

Comment: The problem with the last part is I am not sure how to show $\Gamma(1) = 1$ without using the fact that $\gamma$ is given by $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} - \log(N+1)$.  Is there a way to do it without using that?

Comment: @swygerts How do you propose to define $\gamma$ then?

Comment: Not sure. Was thinking maybe there was another way to do it.  Is there a way to prove the equivalence between this definition of the $\Gamma$ function and the integral definition without invoking $\gamma?$